# SonarQube latest plugin C# 5.6,5.5.2,5.5.1,5.5,5.4 are not working with SonarQube 6.0

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 6.0 version with C# 5.3.2 plugin to analyse C# code. It works OK. Now when I tried using latest C# plugins like C# 5.6,5.5.2,5.5.1,5.5,5.4 and analysed project, I don't see C# related bugs and LOC it shows is zero. So again I switched back to C# 5.3.2 plugin and analysed project I was able to see bugs for C#. It seems like latest all version than C# 5.3.2 are not supportable. Can anyone put light on it.

Comment: Looking at the [Version Matrix](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix) the plugin should be compatible. Did you try to analyse an other project?

Comment: I tried same project using both version C# 5.3.2 and C# 5.6,5.5.2,5.5.1,5.5,5.4. Its working using C# 5.3.2 but when tried later versions it gives zero bugs and LOC also it gives zero.

Comment: Maybe the installation resets the configuration. Check in admin mode which profile/rules are used.